# How to restrict the resize of the toolbar of ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

How to restrict the resize of toolbar not the editor.
user can resize the ckeditor by using resize plugin by dragging the window.i want to restrict the resize of the toolbar but not the editor.

Comment: You mean the horizontal width? That may not be possible. Can you add some more detail?

Comment: Thanx  for the early reply
no not the horizontal width i want to restrict the resize of editors toolbar.means if i resize the editor the text area should get resized and the icons should stay at on place (should not move as the window is resized by dragging it)

Answer (score 1):

Use [inline editor](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html) with [floating user interface](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/floatingui.html). In [classic editor](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/classic.html) the toolbar is fixed to the editing area and they can only be resized together.

Comment: Inline Editor with floating UI will not resolve my problem.i am aware that in classic editor toolbar is fixed with the editor, my question is there any way to restrict the toolbar resizing and allow only the text area resizing??